# Pycharm CSS selector exception - Unable to locate element

Tags: python, pycharm

I am learning to write a voting bot which would submit specific voting form with Pycharm but got error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn.margtop0"}
```

Code line this message comes from below:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.margtop0').click()
```

Link I performed my testing on - https://topservers.com/minecraft/in-183

Am I missing something simple here? Because can't get the thing work.

Comment: you can use driver.find_element_by_name('submit').click(), but your css code is ok. You can try to add explicit wait

Comment: Thank you, odd enough it works with find_element_by_name !